# What is going on with this piece of equipment?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, circuit-design, impedance, voltage-divider

I am working to automate a machine to come back on after a power flicker. There are three things it needs to do when it starts up: power up, restart function A, and restart function B. Power up happens when the electricity is restored but functions A and B have to be turned back on by pushing buttons. These are pretty standard normally-closed buttons, so to simulate pressing them I'm using a microcontroller to operate relays that connect the pins of the buttons when appropriate. In order to know whether to start one or both of the functions on power restore, the microcontroller is constantly polling two inputs and recording the state in EEPROM when the state changes.

Function A is controlled by a board inside the machine that has a set of electrical connectors. 0 is ground, 1, 2, and 3 are all ~7v when function A is on, and are either 0 or 15v when it's not (I haven't been able to identify a pattern as to which one(s) are 0 and which are 15). Connector 4 is always 15v. Connectors 5, 6, and 7 are always ~50v when function A is off and ~8v when it's on.

This all seems weird but it's not impossible to work with. Since 5, 6, and 7 are reliably 50-ish volts when off and 8-ish volts when on, I thought ok I will make a voltage divider and take a tenth of the voltage on an input pin for my microcontroller to detect whether function A is on or off. I put a 47kΩ resistor between the microcontroller input pin and the input meant for pin 7 of the control board. I put another 4.7kΩ resistor between the 47kΩ resistor and ground. I tested it with a multimeter and it seems to be successfully dividing voltage to a tenth of the input voltage.

Here's where it gets weird. I went back to the machine I'm trying to modify and connected pin 7 of the control board to my voltage divider. Instead of the expected 4-5v I expected, I was getting 0.4-0.5v. Did I mislabel my resistors? Did I miscalculate something? I tested it with it turned on, expecting 0.8v if the divider is correct. I got 0.8v. I checked the voltage at the connectors. 0 is still ground, 1-3 are still their weird 0 or 15v when off and 7v when on, 4 is still 15v all the time, but now 5, 6, and 7 are ALL only 4-5v when OFF (still 8-ish volts when on). Even though I only connected these resistors to one of the connectors.

So my question is: What might be going on here, and can I make it safe for my microcontroller if I adjust the voltage divider and treat them as a lower voltage input than what they are when nothing is connected to them?

Comment: Does it have any indicator lights or other more practical stuff you could pick a signal on? If you're worried about your resistors interfering with voltage on the pins, try higher value resistors, if measured voltage gets up when increasing the resistor value it means the resistor is loading it. Note it could also be AC current that your multimeter is not measuring correctly.

Comment: This particular board inside the machine doesn't appear to have any indicator lights of its own. The machine in general uses a digital LCD for its interface, run off a different board. My multimeter reads the value on both AC and DC settings, so I believe it is DC.

Comment: Make sure you know the safety implications of this. There's a reason NVR switches are common on many machines. If the outage is not just a flicker but longer term, power may  be restored at an unexpected time leading to various kinds of hazard (fires after operators have gone home, or machines restarting while people are stumbling around in the dark). This MAY not apply in your case, it's impossible to tell from the question, but unauthorised mods to safety systems may have serious inc. legal implications.

Comment: @BrianDrummond this is definitely important to consider, I agree. This is why it's important that it is able to know the state of the equipment that was last set by the user. The power to this machine goes out for short bursts many times a day. A large switch is shut off altogether when the machine is truly not in use.

Comment: @bobflux I spoke too soon about indicator lights... I found one, but the catch is that it blinks about 1Hz when function A is off, and is powered consistently when function A is on. I can't think of a way to use this to read state of the function setting without slowing my sampling rate to 1Hz.

Comment: Correct about sampling rate, but if you lose power for a while, does one second really make a difference?